# Segmentation Fault in CS50 recover

Tags: c, cs50

I have been trying to find out what is the issue with my code for hours. I referred to other people's code but I still don't know what's wrong. The code compiles fine but the debugger says that the segmentation fault occurs at line 44 (below the comment). Suggestions to improve my code are welcome too. Please help and thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef uint8_t BYTE;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./recover image\n");
        return 1;
    }
    FILE *f = fopen(argv[1],"r");
    if (!f)
    {
        return 2;
    }
    BYTE buffer[512];
    FILE* img = NULL;
    int i = 0;
    while (fread(buffer, 512, 1, f) == 1)
    {
        if (buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff
        && (buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)
        {
            //create jpeg
            char filename[8];
            if (img != NULL)
            {
                fclose(img);
                i++;

                sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg",i);
                img = fopen(filename, "w");
                fwrite(buffer, 512 , 1, img);
            }
            else
            {

                sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg",i);
                img = fopen(filename, "w");
                //error in the line below :(
                fwrite(buffer, 512 , 1, img);
            }
        }
        else if (i > 0)
        {
            fwrite(buffer, 512 , 1, img);
        }

    }
    fclose(img);
    fclose(f);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the most likely failure reason for that line you call out, is that the file handle could be invalid. Hence the *first* thing I would be doing is checking that every file opens correctly, something like:

```
img = fopen(filename, "w");
if (img == NULL) {
    printf("Error opening file '%s'\n", filename);
    exit(1);
}
```

It's generally a good idea to check for failure conditions in functions than can fail, and this also includes the `fwrite` calls:

```
if (fwrite(buffer, 512 , 1, img) != 1) {
    printf("Error writing to file\n");
    exit(1);
}
```